# How to add a Search Widget in action bar in android?

Tags: android, xml

I want to add a search widget to my action bar. i have read tutorials from google developers but their code doesnt work.. pls help me . my Code is as follows:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    /* For The Action Bar Menu. Edit Menu For Adding icons */
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
 return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

First I was Using This Code as below but this also doesn't work:

```
// Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
     /*SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));*/

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

My Manifest Code:

```
<activity
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
        android:name="com.usable.mycodes.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Search Activity Result is for handling searches.

Problem is no Edit text appears after clicking the search button..

Comment: where is your xml layout..@user3291559

Comment: check this link: http://novoda.com/blog/styling-actionbar-searchview

Comment: do not forget to accept the answer if it really helps you out

Answer (score 1):

Use this one...

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.searchview_, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    SearchViewShow(searchItem);

    return true;
}



 private void SearchViewShow(MenuItem searchItem) {

    if (isAlwaysExpanded()) {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    } else {
        searchItem.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
                | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
    }

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if (searchManager != null) {
        List<SearchableInfo> searchables = searchManager.getSearchablesInGlobalSearch();

        SearchableInfo info = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
        for (SearchableInfo inf : searchables) {
            if (inf.getSuggestAuthority() != null
                    && inf.getSuggestAuthority().startsWith("applications")) {
                info = inf;
            }
        }
        mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(info);
    }

    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}

public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    return false;
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

    return false;
}

public boolean onClose() {

    return false;
}

protected boolean isAlwaysExpanded() {
    return false;
}
```

Implements your class with **SearchView.OnQueryTextListener**